# For keyboard accessibility support faced focusing elements issue using tabindex attribute

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

For keyboard accessibility support providing i have used tabindex attribute for focusing elements and while clicking tab on the respective page from last browser options first tab click the UI will not responding or not focused the inner element of the page after second tab click only focused why?

I have included tabindex attribute with 0 for my div elements and added css class for UI,from browser page last element then press first tab not focused expected inner page first element How to handle this ?